# How to get x,y coordinates of a view without touch event in android Programmatically?

Tags: android

I have used the following methods but no success

```
Integer [] location = new Integer[]; 
view.getLocationOnScreen(location); 
getLocationInWindow(int[]) MyCode: int[] locatoins = new int[2]; 
rulerLyt.findViewById(2).getLocationInWindow(locatoins);
x = locatoins[0]; 
float y = 0f; 
y = locatoins[1];
imgBaby.setTranslationX(x); 
imgBaby.setTranslationY(y);
```

Please give your comment/solution to achieve this

Comment: Can you specify what is not working?

Comment: I am not getting the x,y coordinates. I am only getting x=0.0 and y =0.0

Answer (score 1):

These are easily accessible methods of View class.

```
int xCordinate = rulerLyt.findViewById(2).getX();

int yCordinate = rulerLyt.findViewById(2).getY();
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! 

I am getting 0.0 as x,y coordinates 

This is my code:


  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
       /* float x = 0f;
        int[] locatoins = new int[2];
        rulerLyt.findViewById(2).getLocationOnScreen(locatoins);
        x = locatoins[0];
        float y = 0f;
        y = locatoins[1];*/

        float xCordinate = rulerLyt.findViewById(2).getX();

        float yCordinate = rulerLyt.findViewById(2).getY();

        imgBaby.setTranslationX(xCordinate);
        imgBaby.setTranslationY(yCordinate);
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you call provided code just after view creation it will return 0. Because view inflation and measuring are async. They happen on *different iterations* of `MainThread`. You need to to use `ViewTreeObserver` as variant.

```
int[] locatoins = new int[2]; 
rulerLyt.findViewById(2).getLocationInWindow(locatoins);
float x = locatoins[0]; 
float y = locatoins[1];
imgBaby.setTranslationX(x); 
imgBaby.setTranslationY(y);
```

Example of usage of `ViewTreeObserver`

```
view.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(new OnPreDrawListener(){
    void onPreDraw(){
        view.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
        //do your staff
        return true;
    }
})
```